# Imagens na header utlizando docx4J

Tags: table, header, microsoft-word, office-open-xml

Estou utilizando docx4j e todas as imagens que tento colocar na cabeçalho do arquivo Word, não conseguem carregar a imagem.

Alguém tem noção do por quê? Quando eu insiro a imagem no corpo do documento, a imagem é carregada normalmente.

[image: Imagem inserida no cabeçalho]